# Обновление данных в таблице

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

Пытаюсь обновить данные в таблице одной строки

```
echo ' <form method="POST" action="">';
 
    echo '<td><input name="tournaments" type="text" placeholder="'.$myrow['tournaments'].'" /></td>';
 
    echo '<td><input name="win_tournaments" type="text" placeholder="'.$myrow['win_tournaments'].'"/></td>';
 
    echo '<th scope="row"><input class="kn buttons" type="submit" value="Изменить"/></th>';
 
echo ' </form>';
```

```
if (isset($_POST['tournaments']) && isset($_POST['win_tournaments'])) {
 
    $tournaments     = $_POST['tournaments'];
    $win_tournaments    = $_POST['win_tournaments'];
 
    $pl_nick = $myrow['nick'];
 
    $wpdb->update( 
        'tr_participants', // указываем таблицу
        array(
            'tournaments' => "$tournaments",
            'win_tournaments' => "$win_tournaments"),
        array( // где 
            'nick' => $pl_nick
        )
    );
}
```

Данные обновляются, но обновляются сразу во всех строках, а не в одной определённой.
Не пойму где и что я упускаю.
Массив:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [nick] => ChekHyTblu_Fruit
            [deaths_win_tournaments] => 0
            [murder] => 0
            [deaths] => 0
            [tournaments] => 0
            [win_tournaments] => 0
            [vk] => fruit_fellow
            [id_tr] => 1
            [status] => 0
            [stormtrooper] => 0
            [engineer] => 0
            [medic] => 0
            [sniper] => 0
        )
```

Comment: А откуда берется `$pl_nick = $myrow['nick'];`? Просто Вы там используете `$_POST['tournaments'];` и `$_POST['win_tournaments'];` но `nick` берете из переменной `$myrow`.

Comment: Это уже пробы пошли, правильно:  'nick' => $myrow['nick']